# Micropython install RPi.GPIO issue for Pico W

Tags: rpi.gpio, micropython, pi-pico-w

I'm trying to install the RPi.GPIO package on my Raspberry Pi Pico W, but when I run

```
import mip
mip.install('RPi.GPIO')
```

I get the message back

> Installing RPi.GPIO (latest) from https://micropython.org/pi/v2 to /lib
> Package not found: https://micropython.org/pi/v2/package/6/RPi.GPIO/latest.json
> Package may be partially installed

When I run

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

It gives an error, confirming that the package wasn't installed.
The links go to a 404 page so I'm not sure what to do to correct it.

What should I do to successfully download the package?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware RPi.GPIO is only available in Python for the Raspberry Pi, not for the Raspberry Pico.

https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/